# How to avoid convertion of data type when substituting certain values to NaN within a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` and I need to replace certain values to `NaN` based on a filter. I'm facing a change in data type when doing so. How can I avoid this data type conversion?

### Toy example code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
filter = pd.Series([True, True, False, False])
df[filter] = np.nan
```

I would expect df to have `True` and `False` values as well, appart from `NaN`. However `True` values were converted to 1 and `False` values were converted to 0 as seen in below output.

```
>>> df
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

### Partial solution

Only partial solution I can think of now is as follows:

```
df[df==1] = True
df[df==0] = False
print df
```

Which results in:

```
>>> df
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    False
3     True
dtype: object
```

### Question

I know that if I check if a value is 1 and I compare to `True` it resolves to True, and same happens between 0 and `False`. However I would like to avoid my values `True` and `False` to be changed to 0 and 1 respectively when I convert any value to `NaN`. Is this possible so that I don´t need to use the partial solution I stated?

Comment: From a series perspective, it can no longer be of bool type. You can convert it into str though. `df[filter]=str('nan')`

Comment: @mad_ bool and float can coexist within same Serie. Happens I had to set type as object as stated by Wen in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to `object` before filter

```
df = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
filter = pd.Series([True, True, False, False])
df=df.astype('object')
df[filter] = np.nan
df
Out[623]: 
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    False
3     True
dtype: object
```

More info

```
df.apply(type)
Out[625]: 
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2     <class 'bool'>
3     <class 'bool'>
dtype: object
```